# error_log file is getting huge in size

Tags: php, wordpress

**I am using Martfury Theme of Wordpress and getting the following errors in error_log file and this continuously increasing the size of the file**

PHP Warning:  strstr() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/ststocker/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1105

PHP Warning:  stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/ststocker/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1112

PHP Warning:  stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/ststocker/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1115

PHP Warning:  strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/ststocker/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1122

PHP Warning:  explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /home/ststocker/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1123

**the code of functions.php is:**

```
function add_query_arg( ...$args ) {
    if ( is_array( $args[0] ) ) {
        if ( count( $args ) < 2 || false === $args[1] ) {
            $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        } else {
            $uri = $args[1];
        }
    } else {
        if ( count( $args ) < 3 || false === $args[2] ) {
            $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        } else {
            $uri = $args[2];
        }
    }

    $frag = strstr( $uri, '#' );
    if ( $frag ) {
        $uri = substr( $uri, 0, -strlen( $frag ) );
    } else {
        $frag = '';
    }

    if ( 0 === stripos( $uri, 'http://' ) ) {
        $protocol = 'http://';
        $uri      = substr( $uri, 7 );
    } elseif ( 0 === stripos( $uri, 'https://' ) ) {
        $protocol = 'https://';
        $uri      = substr( $uri, 8 );
    } else {
        $protocol = '';
    }

    if ( strpos( $uri, '?' ) !== false ) {
        list( $base, $query ) = explode( '?', $uri, 2 );
        $base                .= '?';
    } elseif ( $protocol || strpos( $uri, '=' ) === false ) {
        $base  = $uri . '?';
        $query = '';
    } else {
        $base  = '';
        $query = $uri;
    }

    wp_parse_str( $query, $qs );
    $qs = urlencode_deep( $qs ); // This re-URL-encodes things that were already in the query string.
    if ( is_array( $args[0] ) ) {
        foreach ( $args[0] as $k => $v ) {
            $qs[ $k ] = $v;
        }
    } else {
        $qs[ $args[0] ] = $args[1];
    }

    foreach ( $qs as $k => $v ) {
        if ( false === $v ) {
            unset( $qs[ $k ] );
        }
    }

    $ret = build_query( $qs );
    $ret = trim( $ret, '?' );
    $ret = preg_replace( '#=(&|$)#', '$1', $ret );
    $ret = $protocol . $base . $ret . $frag;
    $ret = rtrim( $ret, '?' );
    return $ret;
}
```

I have provided the most of the details in this post, please help me out.

Comment: Can you post the full backtrace?

Comment: This is where the error ends up at, but the actual issue is somewhere else.  If you think this error is coming from your theme (changing the theme stops the error, for instance), then you should contact the devs of the theme. Otherwise, you're going to have to do a lot of troubleshooting, such as logging the trace.

Comment: when I disable all the plugin error_log stops generating, and after enabling the plugin this again starts, tried theme switch, plugins one by one but no success

Comment: `when I disable all the plugin error_log stops generating`...have you tried disabling the plugins _one by one_ so you can find out which one is (mostly) responsible for all the log entries?